# Скрипт форм в тильде

Tags: javascript, база-данных, хостинг, формы, tilda

Хочу добавить отзывы товара в тильду необходимо отправление и получение форм.
Как написать скрипт на отдельном хостинге, чтобы он появлялся в тильде?